# What is necessary to make the deploy of a Django Application in an internal network?

Tags: django, networking, deployment, django-rest-framework, web-deployment

I'm a student, making a django project in school for a few months, since last year, using Django Rest Framework and React. A project for a hospital, to manage patients, appointments, medicines, etc. I have asked some questions here a few times on how to do a few things in Django and it was really helpful.

I've presented the system for the people in the hospital, they liked it, there are some adjustments to do yet, going to fix it this weekend. I'm using python anywhere free account to host it. So now I have a few doubts, this month I need to make the deploy of this project in the hospital, they want to host it there for production. They have scheduled a meeting with me, my teacher who is the one guiding me and responsible for this project, and the director of IT of the hospital, the director want me to explain for him what he will need to host the project in the hospital. In my inexperienced head I thought the only thing he will need there is to install python 3.6 and MySQL on their servers. My teacher asked me to make a research of what we are going to need to make the deploy there, before the talk that is scheduled for next week with the director of IT.

So here I'm, I would like to ask you guys, any tips you have, any text I could read about what I will need to deploy a Django application in the hospital network?

One fact that can be useful, when it get in production, there will be at max 7 people online at same time using the system. Django 2.1, python 3.6, rest framework, reactjs, mysql.

Comment: I think you should try https://github.com/dokku/dokku , if you ever tried heroku, so this one is similar. I have some projects based on django which deployed to production server using dokku, mostly I use linode, but since those hospital own their server, you can improvise with it. good luck

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there will be a windows machine in that case you can simply use the inbuilt IIS and configure the Django on IIS and open few ports on the firewall, it's the easiest i belive.
If IIS is not there you can enable it from the windows features like so
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFOWE.png)

and follow this configuration for the starters

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019